# Problem with testing for checkbox being marked

Tags: javascript

I have an input array like

```
<input id='delete[18]' name="delete[18]" value="1" type="checkbox">
<input id='delete[19]' name="delete[19]" value="1" type="checkbox">
```

This Javascript code for check does not work. Why?

```
if (delete_question.19.checked == 1) {
    if (confirm('msg')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw... You don't need the `else` ==> `{if (confirm('msg')) {return true;} return false;}` Since `return ...` ends the function, the only way to get to `return false` is if the conditional wasn't entered.

Comment: @Peter: And as there's only one statement in the `if` block, you can leave out the accolades (around `return true;`), too.

Comment: @Marcel - True. I've just added a second line w/o remembering to put the accolades in enough times that I don't like to *write* it that way.... but I do prefer to *read* it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (document.getElementById('myForm')['delete[19]'].checked) {
   return confirm('msg');
}
```

Comment: Fast typing than my answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because the DOM for HTML forms doesn't work anything like PHP's form data parsing engine.

You want something more like:

```
document.forms.id_of_form.elements['delete[19]']
```

Note: Use of square bracket notation because dot notation can't access properties that include [ or ] characters.

BTW, an HTML id cannot include the characters [ or ] (although names can) so the HTML is invalid.